# Question about $Var(X)<\infty$

Tags: probability

Is it true that $Var(X)<\infty$ implies that $\sum_n E(|X|1_{|X|\ge n}<\infty)$? I could use this result in a problem I am working on, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Take expectations on both sides of 
$$|X|\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1}_{|X|\geq n}=|X|\lfloor |X|\rfloor\leq X^2.$$

Comment: What does the floor function of that random variable mean? I am a little confused by your notation.

Comment: @6723Excelsior It means that you plug $|X|$ into the floor function.

Comment: Why is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{|x|\ge n}$ equal to that floor function? I am really confused by that equality

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I think you want $1_{\{n+1 > |X| \ge n\}}$ in the summantion.

Comment: I originally was successful proving it if you use $1_{n+1>|X|\ge n}$, but it turns out I think I need this stronger result.

Comment: @6723Excelsior The expression $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{x\geq n}$ counts the number of positive integers less than or equal to $x$, and so for $x\geq 0$, it is the same as $\lfloor x\rfloor$.